# ClassNotFoundException build through maven

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, classnotfoundexception

I am using maven to build my project. I wanted to create assembly jar including some of the dependencies, so I wrote my custom assembly descriptor.

POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.guavus</groupId>
  <artifactId>Exporter</artifactId>
  <version>atlas2.1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Exporter</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <aspectj.version>1.6.10</aspectj.version>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.guavus.exporter.Exporter</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>/Users/archit.thakur/Documents/Code_dev_cdn_mapreduce/exporter/src/main/configurator.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
          <!--
          <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>     
              -->
          <finalName>Exporter-${project.version}</finalName>
          <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>


  <dependencies>
    <!-- local snapshots  -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.guavus</groupId>
      <artifactId>CubeCreator</artifactId>
      <version>atlas2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.guavus</groupId>
      <artifactId>ConcurrentFlows</artifactId>
      <version>atlas2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ps</groupId>
      <artifactId>thriftGenerated</artifactId>
      <version>atlas2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- local snapshots  --><!-- local 3rd Party -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>apache</groupId>
      <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
      <version>0.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- local 3rd Party --><!-- remote 3rd Party -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
      <version>0.20.203.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- remote 3rd Party --><!-- test libs --><!-- test libs -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

DESCRIPTOR:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>dep</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>

  <dependencySets>

    <dependencySet>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
      <includes>
        <include>log4j:log4j</include>
        <include>org.slf4j:slf4j-api</include>
        <include>ch.qos.logback:logback-access</include>
        <include>ch.qos.logback:logback-classic</include>
        <include>ch.qos.logback:logback-core</include>
        <include>com.guavus:Exporter</include>
      </includes>
    </dependencySet>

  </dependencySets>

</assembly>
```

The problem is, It is creating jar having classes at directory structure like "Exporter-atlas2.1//". For example, "Exporter-atlas2.1/ch/qos/logback/classic/util/EnvUtil.class". Thats why, it throws, ClassNotFoundException at the runtime. I was expecting classes to be present at "/",For eg. "ch/qos/logback/classic/util/EnvUtil.class".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
```

in the assemly configurator resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't Exporter-atlas2.1 just the name of your jar (since it's set as the finalName) and when you unpack you get this directory as parent of the unpacked dependencies?

Comment: If I do not unpack, it throws "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (make-assembly) on project Exporter: Failed to create assembly: Error adding file 'com.guavus:Exporter:jar:atlas2.1' to archive: /Users/archit.thakur/Documents/Code_dev_cdn_mapreduce/exporter/target/classes isn't a file."

Comment: The above issue got resolved. I did unpack = false. removed my project depence form the dependency set. It works. but it still pushes the jars inside the folder "Exporter-atlas2.1" rather than placing them directly. Idea on issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know if this will solve your issue, but you can specify an

```
<outputDirectory>
```

for a `<dependencySet>`. However, as you unpack the dependency, this might not be the right solution.

BTW, why do you unpack ?

Comment: If I do not unpack, it throws "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (make-assembly) on project Exporter: Failed to create assembly: Error adding file 'com.guavus:Exporter:jar:atlas2.1' to archive: /Users/archit.thakur/Documents/Code_dev_cdn_mapreduce/exporter/target/classes isn't a file."

Comment: The above issue got resolved. I did unpack = false. removed my project depence form the dependency set. It works. but it still pushes the jars inside the folder "Exporter-atlas2.1" rather than placing them directly. Idea on issue.

Comment: I updated my answer, as it was not displayed correctly (bad formatting).

Comment: I think what I propose can solve the issue of the output folder